# How to force model.matrix/model.Matrix() to keep the original order of factor levels…?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a simple hypothetical pedigree

```
> dam <- c(0,  0,  0,  0,  2,  4,  5, 6,  9, 1000)
> sire <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 3, 8, 7)
> ID <- c(1:length(dam))
```

So, in terms of data.frame, my pedigree is as follow:

```
> pedigree <- data.frame(ID, dam, sire) 
> pedigree
   ID  dam sire
1   1    0    0
2   2    0    0
3   3    0    0
4   4    0    0
5   5    2    1
6   6    4    3
7   7    5    1
8   8    6    3
9   9    9    8
10 10 1000    7
```

Based on dam and sire variables, I have created a family field (*family=damxsire*, only when both dam and sire are different to zero, *NA* in another case), i.e.

```
> datafam <- pedigree %>% 
mutate(family=ifelse((sire==0 | dam==0), NA, as.vector(paste(dam, sire, sep="x")))) %>%
   mutate_at(vars(family), as.factor)
```

```
> datafam
   ID  dam sire family
1   1    0    0   <NA>
2   2    0    0   <NA>
3   3    0    0   <NA>
4   4    0    0   <NA>
5   5    2    1    2x1
6   6    4    3    4x3
7   7    5    1    5x1
8   8    6    3    6x3
9   9    9    8    9x8
10 10 1000    7 1000x7
```

and from my *family* variable, I want to get a design matrix (*Zfam*), that is

```
> form1 <- formula(~ family -1) 
> termsf1 <- terms(form1, keep.order = TRUE) 
> mf1 <- model.frame(termsf1, data=datafam, na.action= na.pass)
> Zfam <- as.matrix(MatrixModels::model.Matrix(form1, mf1, sparse=FALSE))
> Zfam[is.na(Zfam)] <- 0 # replaces any missing values in Z by zeros
```

The resulting matrix is:

```
> Zfam
   family1000x7 family2x1 family4x3 family5x1 family6x3 family9x8
1             0         0         0         0         0         0
2             0         0         0         0         0         0
3             0         0         0         0         0         0
4             0         0         0         0         0         0
5             0         1         0         0         0         0
6             0         0         1         0         0         0
7             0         0         0         1         0         0
8             0         0         0         0         1         0
9             0         0         0         0         0         1
10            1         0         0         0         0         0
```

For some unknown reason, model.Matrix reorders the family levels, so that the family *1000x7* appears first. The problem is that for a post-analysis, I need the *Zfam* matrix to be built based on the original order of the data (original order of family levels).

Expected output

```
> Zfam
   family2x1 family4x3 family5x1 family6x3 family9x8 family1000x7 
1          0         0         0         0         0         0 
2          0         0         0         0         0         0 
3          0         0         0         0         0         0 
4          0         0         0         0         0         0 
5          1         0         0         0         0         0 
6          0         1         0         0         0         0 
7          0         0         1         0         0         0 
8          0         0         0         1         0         0 
9          0         0         0         0         1         0 
10         0         0         0         0         0         1
```

On the other hand, I think that an additional issue is concerned to the way to R sorts character vectors. For example, family *1000x7* was moved from the last to the first position (and here begins my headache)

```
> datafam[with(datafam, order(family)), ]
   ID  dam sire family
10 10 1000    7 1000x7
5   5    2    1    2x1
6   6    4    3    4x3
7   7    5    1    5x1
8   8    6    3    6x3
9   9    9    8    9x8
1   1    0    0   <NA>
2   2    0    0   <NA>
3   3    0    0   <NA>
4   4    0    0   <NA>
```

I also tried with another impractical approach. For example, using model.matrix function (from stats package), see the following code

```
> form1 <- formula(~ family -1)
> termsf1 <- terms(form1, keep.order = TRUE)
> mf1 <- model.frame(termsf1, data=datafam, na.action= na.pass)
> Zfam <- as.matrix(stats::model.matrix(form1, mf1, sparse=FALSE))
> Zfam[is.na(Zfam)] <- 0 # replaces any missing values in Z by zeros
```

However, I got the same previous result…

For now, my workaround has been to sort the data in the same way it is sorted by the model.Matrix (from MatrixModel or stats packages). However, this artificial ordering of the data will give me problems for the rest of the analysis (this stage is just the beginning of an extensive analysis). I'm sure there is a better/efficient way to do this task ...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of columns in matrix is based on the factor levels that you have in `family` column. So you can assign the factor levels in the order you want them.

In this case you want then in the order they appear so you can use `unique`.

```
library(dplyr)

datafam <- pedigree %>% 
  mutate(family=ifelse((sire==0 | dam==0), NA, paste(dam, sire, sep="x")),
         family = factor(family, levels = unique(family)))

form1 <- formula(~ family -1) 
termsf1 <- terms(form1, keep.order = TRUE) 
mf1 <- model.frame(termsf1, data=datafam, na.action= na.pass)
Zfam <- as.matrix(MatrixModels::model.Matrix(form1, mf1, sparse=FALSE))
Zfam[is.na(Zfam)] <- 0
Zfam

#   family2x1 family4x3 family5x1 family6x3 family9x8 family1000x7
#1          0         0         0         0         0            0
#2          0         0         0         0         0            0
#3          0         0         0         0         0            0
#4          0         0         0         0         0            0
#5          1         0         0         0         0            0
#6          0         1         0         0         0            0
#7          0         0         1         0         0            0
#8          0         0         0         1         0            0
#9          0         0         0         0         1            0
#10         0         0         0         0         0            1
```

Comment: Thank Ronak for your answer, Zfam matrix keep the original order of factor levels. However, now family 1000x7 is missing, and therefore, its coefficient (value=1) is zero in the design matrix, please check Zfam resulting with your approach and compare with the expected output.

Comment: @Rob Okay corrected the `datafam` step. Can you check the updated answer?

Comment: Thank a lot Ronak...!, now Zfam matrix look according to expectation :-)